# Mobile submenubar not selected (using bootstrap.css)

Tags: html, css

On a mobile browser, user able to select main menu but its sub menu does not get selected.

Here is the HTML I am using:

```
<html>
    <body>    
        <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
          <div class="navbar-inner">
            <div class="container">
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-navbar" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".nav-collapse">
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
              </button>
               <a  style="float:right;margin-top:10px;" href="index.php"><span style="font-weight: lighter; font-size: 14px;color: #FF3333">&nbsp;Logout</span> </a>
                 <a style="float:right;margin-top:10px;color:#FFFFFF;text-decoration:none;" ><span style="font-size:13px;color:#FFFFFF; font-weight:normal;">|&nbsp;<?php echo $_SESSION["username"];?>&nbsp;|</span></a>
              <div class="nav-collapse collapse">
                <ul class="nav">

                  <li class="dropdown">
                    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Masters <b class="caret"></b></a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                        <li><a href="createdoctor.php">Create Doctor</a></li>
                        <li><a href="createchemist.php">Create Chemist</a></li>
                        <li><a href="createstockist.php">Create Stockist</a></li>
                        <li><a href="createemployee.php">Create Employee</a></li>
                        <li><a href="createproduct.php">Create Product</a></li>
                        <li><a href="areamaster.php">Create Area</a></li>
                        <li><a href="Manager.php">Add Manager under Employee</a></li>
                      </ul>
                  </li>
        <?php
        }
       ?>                 
                <li class="dropdown">
                    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Transactions<b class="caret"></b></a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                        <li><a href="tourpgm_prev.php">Tour Program</a></li>
                        <li><a href="reportmaster_prev.php">Report Master</a></li>
                        <li><a href="expense_prev.php">Expense Sheet </a></li>
                        <li><a href="leave.php">Leave Master </a></li>                 

                        <li><a href="scoremcard.php">Monthly Score Card</a></li>
                        <li><a href="emptourpgm.php">Employee Tour Program</a></li>
        </ul>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

If that is all your code, then remove the

```
    <?php
    }
   ?>
```

section in the final third.